# Excel 2016 Stopping automatic formatting of timestamps

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, formatting

I'm entering a list of timestamps from a video into Excel 2016. However, when I reach numbers above 24, Excel reacts like it's a 24 hour clock and changes my number. For example, if my timestamp is at 25:30, my cell will read 1:30. In the bar at the top, it reads "1900-01-01  1:30:00 AM." In the Format Cells window, it says that I have a custom format of h:mm.

When I change the format to number, a cell with an input of 25:30 reads as 1.06. When I change the format to text, it reads as 1.0625.

How do I format my cells to read as amounts of time instead of clock readings?

Comment: Format the cell as `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: Use a custom format: `[h]:mm:ss`

Comment: Did you check the cell format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, I've landed on a solution. For times under 1 hour, I used the cell format `[h]:mm`, and for times over 1 hour, I used the cell format `hh:mm:ss`, since the original issue only applied to times over 24 minutes and under 1 hour.